# Creating Right-Aligned Triangles with Asterisks

Tags: java

I am trying to print right aligned triangles using asterisks. So far I have a program that asks a user for a shape and then a size, then prints out a triangle with those dimensions. So far I have a program for left aligned triangles. How do I make it so it's right aligned? Here is my code so far.

```
if (shape.equals("triangle")) {

    System.out.print("size?");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i = i + 1) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j = j+ 1) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: so you would want some padding - right?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding some padding on the left:

```
System.out.print("size?");
int size = sc.nextInt();
// input 5
for (int i = 0; i <= size; i = i + 1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size-i; ++j) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will add left padding and as result, you'll get a right-aligned triangle:

```
int star = 1, space = size - 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < space; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < star; i++) {
            System.out.print("#");
        }
        star = star + 1;
        space = space - 1;
        --size;
        System.out.println("");
    }
```